# D3JS Bar Chart Tooltip, translating from vertical to horizontal

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to translate a tooltip used for a vertical bar chart to one used for a horizontal bar chart. I've gotten the bars to highlight on mouse-over, but the tooltip isn't appearing. So my question is what am I missing? Is there a place where I need to set the direction of the tooltip? Or am I not calling the tooltip correctly?

Here is my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JhMRSAvxmvjqP4kE3X5v?p=preview

```
<style>    
    .d3-tip {
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>% Change in Income:</strong> <span style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + d.name;
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling your tooltip correctly. You need to call `mouseover` and `mouseout` for the bars so they know when to display the tooltip. You can do that by adding 2 lines like the following:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.value)); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0)); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .on('mouseover', tip.show) //show tooltip when hovering over bar
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide); //hide tooltip when not hovering over bar
```

Additionally, you need to also include this line after you declare your `svg` variable so it calls your tooltip function:

```
svg.call(tip);
```

Updated Plunkr here - http://plnkr.co/edit/X3O44dBuOGzEkqjUkyUC?p=preview

Comment: This is very useful. I should have known the svg.call(tip) as it was in the original that I was translating from. The two lines you added I probably wouldn't have figured out, though. Very much appreciated!